# is it possible to override $CI_PROJECT_NAME in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to specify a CI_PROJECT_NAME different from the actual project name in gitlab?

Comment: why do you need this? explain please

Comment: lets say curiosity. Ignoring the X to my Y problem (which I have solved independantly), I now would like to know an answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the env var on the script section of you job

```
script:
  - CI_PROJECT_NAME=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Via the Gitlab GUI:

1. Navigate to your Repository Settings > CI/CD > Variables
2. Add the variable `CI_PROJECT_NAME` there

Worked for me, anyway.